# Let's get critical: Oct 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange](http://gardening.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Need some help identifying a plum tree](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/8171/need-some-help-identifying-a-plum-tree)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Which is preferred: worm castings or worm casting tea?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/8189/which-is-preferred-worm-castings-or-worm-casting-tea)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Should a citrus tree growing very close to the house be killed?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/8365/should-a-citrus-tree-growing-very-close-to-the-house-be-killed)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Is a 3 foot wide raised bed versatile enough?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/8158/is-a-3-foot-wide-raised-bed-versatile-enough)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Why are my tomato fruits developing black, mushy spots before they can ripen?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/8173/why-are-my-tomato-fruits-developing-black-mushy-spots-before-they-can-ripen)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Bonsai Leaves on new shoots rather than existing branches](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/8263/bonsai-leaves-on-new-shoots-rather-than-existing-branches)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Painting concrete pots to help conserve water](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/8328/painting-concrete-pots-to-help-conserve-water)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Common causes of burnt tips on herbs](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/8354/common-causes-of-burnt-tips-on-herbs)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Propagate an apple tree](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/propagate-an-apple-tree)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Mystery in Pennsylvania garden](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/8344/mystery-in-pennsylvania-garden)

  **Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 3)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is appropriate to ask me to rate questions that I have provided an answer for.  Is it possible to filter what is shown to each user to exclude questions they have participated in ?

Comment: Remember, you're rating the question, too. If Your idea was implemented in the [Oct 2014 Site Self-Evaluation](http://meta.gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/588/lets-get-critical-oct-2014-site-self-evaluation), I would only have been able to rate 2 of the ten questions.